# Crop image to be circular swift 3

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, drawing, crop

So I have this issue I have been trying to solve for the past few days however, cannot find a solution to the problem. My issue is very simple I am trying to crop a image so that it becomes a circle. From research done, I have found a few methods that can be used to achieve this and the main one which seemed to pop up a lot is to simply crop the UIImageView so that it becomes a circular frame. The code which I used to do this can be seen below.

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height/2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

The only problem is that this method only crops the frame of the image view and not the image itself. So if I was to save the image to the users camera roll for instance, it would still appear as a rectangle and not a cropped circle. I am a bit lost with how I can actually achieve this as I am relatively new to Xcode and was hoping that someone might be able to provide a method as to how I can crop the image itself not just the frame. Any help on the topic will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the content view of the imageView? Also please add a screenshot of how your image looks.

Comment: I think you should set border radius color and border width for layer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular cropping Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495024/circular-cropping-swift-3)

Comment: Do not duplicate your own question. If you didn't get decent answers on your original question, edit it.

Comment: Hi its not actually a duplicate it is a very similar question but if you look at them closely you will see they are different. This one is about altering the photo itself while the last question was about the aspect of the image inside an image view as well as cropping the image view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets get on **Graphics Context
**.

[image]

```
func makeRoundImg(img: UIImageView) -> UIImage {
    let imgLayer = CALayer()
    imgLayer.frame = img.bounds
    imgLayer.contents = img.image?.cgImage;
    imgLayer.masksToBounds = true;

    imgLayer.cornerRadius = 28 //img.frame.size.width/2

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.bounds.size)
    imgLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return roundedImage!;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use semicolons in Swift unless you have several expressions in a single line.

Comment: Have recently started swift from objC. I will take care of it from next time always.. thanks :) :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this code for **swift 3**, first you need to kept the imageView content mode as Aspect Fit.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let profilePicture = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")
    self.imgView.image = profilePicture.circleMasked
   }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

  extension UIImage {
  var isPortrait:  Bool    { return size.height > size.width }
  var isLandscape: Bool    { return size.width > size.height }
  var breadth:     CGFloat { return min(size.width, size.height) }
  var breadthSize: CGSize  { return CGSize(width: breadth, height: breadth) }
  var breadthRect: CGRect  { return CGRect(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize) }
  var circleMasked: UIImage? {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(breadthSize, false, scale)
      defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
      guard let cgImage = cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: isLandscape ? floor((size.width - size.height) / 2) : 0, y: isPortrait  ? floor((size.height - size.width) / 2) : 0), size: breadthSize)) else { return nil }
      UIBezierPath(ovalIn: breadthRect).addClip()
      UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: imageOrientation).draw(in: breadthRect)
      return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following also make sure Height and width should b of same size, else it will appear as oval Or result will be unwanted.

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height/2
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
imageVoew.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Changes to the `UIImageView` only change the way the image is __displayed__ on the UI, they don't actually change the underlying image object.