# How can I get an ImagePicker to produce a standard round image for all users in Firebase?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

So I have an image picker but it doesn't force images to be cut in a circle so that they are uniform.

I have tried to use CropViewController and RSKImageCropper but have gotten various errors.

```
 @IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode  = .photo
    } else {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary    
    }
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)       
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true     
}
```

////then down further

```
func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: TOCropViewController?, didCropToCircularImage image: UIImage?, with cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
    // 'image' is the newly cropped, circular version of the original image
}
```

UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

```
extension FeedVC : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        self.takenImage = image
        self.UIImageView.image = self.takenImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if UIImageView.image == nil {
             //Do stuff for nil image
        }
    }

   func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

At the end of it all, what I need is for the image picker to crop the images in a circle so that it is uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also crop image square size e.g 40x40 after that set the UIImageView properties for circle visibility.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2
}
```

And be sure imageView constraints have 1:1 aspect ratio

Comment: Thanks. It says Use of unresolved identifier 'imageView'

Comment: You have to connect outlets from interface builder, for recognize to objects in interface inside of viewController code.

Comment: aah I see. That makes sense. My outlet was called:  @IBOutlet weak var UIImageView: UIImageView!. However, if I use UIImageView.ClipToBounds = true, I get an error Value of type 'UIImageView?' has no member 'ClipToBounds'. Do you know why that may be? I am using the latest swift

Comment: it should be clipsToBounds, sorry :(

Comment: No problem. Thanks :) This fixed the code error and solved the cropping half way. After I used the image picker, it did display in circle, but the image picket itself was still a large square. As a result, when I fetch the image from the database in another page (the page that really matters), the image still displays in square. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You can set image to circle after cropping square 
Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299926/crop-image-to-be-circular-swift-3

Comment: Thanks. I used the winning answer's code. No build errors but it doesn't change anything to the square pics. Is is possible to immediately make the image picker pic a standard round image in stead of a square?